# I want to get two integers from a user via a text input, find the difference between the two numbers and divide that number by 25. How do I do this?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, getelementbyid, document.write

I'm making a small website as a test. Very new to JavaScript and HTML forms so I thought i'd throw myself into what I consider to be the deep end and give it a go.

I'm trying to get an interger to be displayed on the page, that is  the result of a few calculations.

I want to find the difference between the first number (current value), and the second number (desired value) and then divide that number by 25 and store that as a variable. I then want to display that variable inside a message.

My current HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
    <title>MMR calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Type in your current MMR, and your desired MMR and click "Calculate"</h1>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="currentRating" placeholder="What is your current MMR?">
    <input type="text" id="desiredRating" placeholder="What is your desired MMR?">
    <input type="submit" onclick="calculate()">
</form>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My current JavaScript :

```
function calculate() {
    var currentRating = document.getElementById("currentRating");
    var desiredRating = document.getElementById("desiredRating");

    var difference = desiredRating - currentRating;
    var gamesToPlay = difference / 25;

    document.write("You need to play " + gamesToPlay + " to get to " + desiredRating);
}
```

Comment: What's the question? Are you having any errors? Besides the `ddocument.write` with a double `d`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are 99% there. All you have to do is change

```
var currentRating = document.getElementById("currentRating");
var desiredRating = document.getElementById("desiredRating");
```

into

```
var currentRating = parseInt(document.getElementById("currentRating").value);
var desiredRating = parseInt(document.getElementById("desiredRating").value);
```

The way you had it, those variables just held the HTML (technically, DOM) elements themselves, and not the values that were in them. This gets the values and then turns them into integers so you can do math with them. If you do this, your site do exactly what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful:

```
var currentRating = document.getElementById("currentRating").value;
```

is a String (text) value... to be sure of int value you can do

```
try{
   var currentRatingInt = parseInt(currentRating);
}catch(e){
  alert(currentRating + " is not an integer");
}
```

If you like to display result in page you can use a DIV with and id and do:

```
document.getElementById("idOfYourDiv").innerHTML  = "What you like to display in div";
```

Answer (score 0):

hope this code will help :

html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css">
    <title>MMR calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Type in your current MMR, and your desired MMR and click "Calculate"</h1>
<div>
    <input type="text" id="currentRating" placeholder="What is your current MMR?">
    <input type="text" id="desiredRating" placeholder="What is your desired MMR?">
    <button onclick="calculate();">Calculate</button>
</div>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript :

```
function calculate() {
    var currentRating = document.getElementById("currentRating").value;
    var desiredRating = document.getElementById("desiredRating").value;

    var gamesToPlay = (desiredRating - currentRating) / 25;
    gamesToPlay = Math.abs( parseInt(gamesToPlay) );

   alert("You need to play " + gamesToPlay + " to get to " + desiredRating);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Subtract first field from the other, and if the value is not greater than 0 multiply by `-1`.

Divide that by 25.